# How to extract one generic method from several duplicating code methods like this?

Tags: c#, generics, refactoring, duplicates

I got 3 classes, all inherited from one base class 'A', so I call them A1, A2, A3. Another 3 class inherited from 'B', called B1, B2, B3.
Now I created 3 methods to do the same work, like this:

```
List<A1> Do(List<B1>);
List<A2> Do(List<B2>); 
List<A3> Do(List<B3>);
```

Which have same logic and codes, the only difference is the different new method for the 3 class:

```
B1 b = new B1(...) in method 1
B2 b = new B2(...)  in method 2 
B3 b = new B3(...)  in method 3.
```

So can somebody help me to figure out how to generic one method from these 3?

I need to add something about B1 constructor, things become more complicated since I used several constructors, some is like this:

```
B1(A1, int)
```

And some is like this:

```
B1(A1)
```

Comment: How is `A` and `B` and the rest actually defined?

Comment: It's hard to tell you what the best solution is when we don't know what's being passed into your derived classes' constructors. A little bit more sample code is in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a delegate into the method to decide the exact type of the object being created, like this:

```
List<AX> Do<AX,BX>(List<BX> b, Func<AX,int?,BX> make) where AX : A, BX : B {
    ...
}
```

Now you can pass a lambda for your `make` parameter, like this:

```
var listB2 = new List<B2>();
var res = Do(listB2, (a, num) => num.HasValue ? new B2(a, num.Value) : B2(a));
```

Comment: What should I do if I used more than one constructor of B1 in the method?

Comment: @Gavin I edited the answer to support two constructors of `B2`.'

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how what `Bx` constructors look like. My first guess will be

```
public List<TOutput> Do<TInput, TOutput>(
    List<TInput> input, 
    Func<..., TOutput> outputCreator)
```

And then

```
var a1 = Do(b1, (...) => new B1(...));
```

So the main question here is what the `...` part should be.

Comment: What should I do if I used more than one constructor of B1 in the method?

Comment: @Gavin That's not pretty, but you can have as many `outputCreator`s as you see fit.